# Historical data on a driving route

Tags: travel

I'm looking for something that would give statistics on my daily commute.

A friend of mine is thinking about leaving their job because the daily driving commute is too dangerous.  Nearly got into two major accidents in the first two weeks.

What would be interesting to investigate different times of travel, maybe reroute suggestions, based on different times of the year etc.  lots of ideas but nothing comes to mind except tell the friend to go with their gut.

And yes "drive slower" has been offered as a suggestion.  It would be interesting to know what lanes could be more dangerous too.

I'm looking for software recommendations to help in this real life scenario.

Any OS any software any website is acceptable.

Comment: What a pleasure daily commute always is! Sounds to me like you are looking for something like TomTom's data ([TomTom Traffic](https://www.tomtom.com/en_us/trafficindex/) offers reroute based on real-time data, though at the beginning, it used history data that still may be accounted for in their suggestion algorithm; they also have [statistics they can sell](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/2/3f80e432-7199-11e0-9b7a-00144feabdc0.html) about average speed and so on, but I don't think these are available publicly).

Comment: @quincy Are you only interested in historical data, as the title of your question suggest, or you'd be interested in real-time data as well (or as an alternative)? Since you mentioned times of travel and re-route suggestions, one might be look at those from a real-time point of view too, especially when driving.

Comment: @quincy I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but... do you know [waze](https://www.waze.com/)? _Get alerted before you approach police, accidents, road hazards or traffic jams, all shared by other drivers in real-time._ Even though it doesn't give you historical data (as far as I know), it might be worth a try.

Comment: Thx.  Yeah I know waze.  Unfortunately it's real time.  I would like historical

Comment: Looking for software that is done not data